# Работа платы Arduino Nano без программатора

Tags: c++, arduino, электроника

Имеется плата Arduino Nano с, вероятнее всего, перегоревшим программатором. Можно ли загружать скетчи без него?

Comment: можно загружать скетчи другим программатором; в качестве такового можно использовать другую arduino, подключив её к первой по SPI.

Answer (score 0):

Ардуино Нано в качестве программатора использует FT232RL, или аналогичную микросхему. Эта микросхема создаёт виртуальный COM порт по которому и происходит общение микроконтроллера и компьютера. Если эта микросхема сгорела, то можно подключиться к Rx и Tx контактам контроллера напрямую - они выведены на D0 и D1 соответственно. И пересылать UART сигнал напрямую.

Как вариант - использовать настоящий COM порт (если где-то ещё он есть). Единственная проблема там - уровни сигнала. COM порт это RS-232, логическая 1 там представлена напряжением -15 вольт, а логический ноль +15 вольт. В то время как логические уровни микроконтроллера 0 вольт для логического 0 и +5 вольт для логической 1. Т.е. нужен будет преобразователь уровней (например, микросхема MAX232).

Но, по сути, подойдёт любой виртуальный COM порт, даже с другой платы Ардуино.

P.S. Эту микросхему можно заменить, это не очень сложно и она не требует прошивки.

Comment: Пардон, а каким образом напрямую подключаться к контактам?

Comment: Она выведены на пины D0 и D1

Comment: Не в этом смысле. Плата подключена к ноутбуку. Если я правильно понял, то по одному контакту к D0 и D1. А вторые-то куда включать?

Answer (score 0):

У Arduino Nano (как и у большинства других) есть 6-контактная колодка для подключения ISP-программатора. Сам программатор можно купить готовый за пару долларов или собрать самостоятельно, например, из второй Arduino.